# Need to show Image on Pin Pointer on MapView

Tags: iphone

For map-view the pin pointer..

It show's title... for location... and subtitle ...

Now for the same box in pin point.
Need to show image. how to show image on pin.. pointer.[any static image.]

- (NSString *)title
- (NSString *)subtitle

This both are working fine...

How to do about the image on the pin pointer.

@thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean adding an image to your MKAnnotationView is that right ? The image you can add is part of the `MKAnnotationView`, not part of the `MKAnnotation`.
See property `image` of the `MKAnnotationView`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WeatherMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491) apple example. Good luck.

Comment: @Texente alex... Thanks for replay ... Do i have any other link.